# How to inherit a value in a belongs_to model from its has_many parent model during its creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 models: a user that has_many tools (which belongs_to user).
Each user has an address. When a user list a new tool, the address will have the same address as its owner.
In an ordinary case, I would just call tool.user.address and would get its address.
However, I am trying to use geocoding for the tools, and it does not accept neither this type of call, nor the "delegate :address, to: :user".

I was wondering if there is a way to pass the address from the user when they create a new tool, and how to do so.
Also, would it be possible to automatically update the tool's address if/when the user changes its address?
Thank you!

```
  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.string "name"
    t.string "address"
    t.string "phone"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.float "latitude"
    t.float "longitude"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end
```

```
  create_table "tools", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.float "price"
    t.bigint "user_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "rating"
    t.string "address", :user
    t.float "latitude"
    t.float "longitude"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_tools_on_user_id"
  end
```

Comment: The error message is telling you that your tools table lacks the latitude and longitude columns needed to store its position. If you're using the Postgres PostGIS extension and the ActiveRecord adapter you can alternatively use its native st_point geography types instead of two columns. https://pganalyze.com/blog/postgis-rails-geocoder

Comment: "Also, would it be possible to automatically update the tool's address if/when the user changes its address?" - yeah and no. You could use a callback to do this automatically but it might be better in the long run to do this is explicitly - for example in a service object.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out, if someone looks for it later:

Just had to add this to the controller inside the create action, before save:

`@tool.address = current_user.address`